# How to use leaflet in the Vue (or Vuetify) playground?

Tags: leaflet, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I have a problem using `leaflet.js` in my Vuetify app, but I can't show it properly here because I haven't managed to set up one of the 'playgrounds' (Vue or Vuetify) to use `leaflet`.  [This is what I have tried](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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).
If someone can get a map showing in a playground, I can then modify the code to show my actual problem! Vuetify preferred but the methods are probably similar.
Thanks

Comment: I think leaflet won't work in a playground or snippet, the sources contain relative links to images, which cannot be resolved without a build step (afaik). There are sandboxes that you can use though, like https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vue3-leaflet-kxrup

Comment: Thanks. I forked that sample and tried to add Vuetify, but it doesn't recognise the Vuetify components. Do you know what I'm missing? https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vue3-leaflet-forked-yxcqlc?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue%3A10%2C27

Comment: In main.js, it looks like you only import the directives, but not the components

Comment: Yes, I did. In my actual project I use vite so don't need to import the components in `main.js`. But importing them into sandboxio gives an error 'import declarations may only appear at top level of a module' . So the sandbox seems buggy and is _extremely_ slow at updating! Thanks for suggestion anyway